# How many nonnegative integer matrices of size $N$ have all row and column sums equal to $D$?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations, combinations, magic-square

Given the positive integer $N$ and $D$, generate all the non-negative integer matrices which satisfy

1. matrix dimension is $N\times N$;
2. sum of each row elements equals to $D$
3. sum of each column elements equals to $D$

when $N\leq 5, D\leq 8$, there are how many matrices in each $\langle N,D\rangle $.

Comment: This isn't so easy. There are research papers on the number of such matrices. For the given parameters, might be simplest just to bung it on a computer and count the matrices. This looks useful: http://drvinceknight.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/counting-semi-magic-squares-using.html

Comment: Have you had a look?

Comment: Sorry, i am late. you know the damned GFW, i can't get into the link, can you copy that or show me another one.

Comment: It's a bit long to copy. Can you send email to the guy who wrote it, KnightVA at cardiff.ac.ukq (but leave off the q at the end)?

Comment: Thanks, i have bypassed the GFW, i have read the blog, i got this: 

1. the matrix that satisfies these condition is called semi magic matrix. 

2. |SMS(3,r)|=C(44,r)+C(34,r)+C(24,r) 

3. |SMS(n,2)|=taylor(f(x),x,0,n).coeff(x^n)*(factorial(n)^2), f(x) = e ^ (x / 2)/(sqrt(1 - x)) 

But when n,r are others, what's the result?

Comment: I don't know. I'll repeat my suggestion that you slap it on a computer and just try to count them. I did find a couple of other papers that should help: MR0332532 (48 #10859), Ehrhart, Eugène, Sur les carrés magiques, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B 277 (1973), A651–A654. Author's summary: "Le nombre de carrés magiques de côté $c$ et de somme $n$ est un polynôme en $n$ de degré $(c−1)^2$. MR0317970 (47 #6519), Stanley, Richard P, Linear homogeneous Diophantine equations and magic labelings of graphs, Duke Math. J. 40 (1973), 607–632. (continued)

Comment: The Stanley paper says, Let $H_n(r)$ denote the number of squares of side $n$, with nonnegative integral entries in each of the $n^2$ cells into which the square can be divided, such that every line-sum in the direction of an edge is $r$. The reviewer noted that $H_n(r)$ is a polynomial in $r$ of degree $d=(n-1)^2$ with rational coefficients, satisfying the relations $H_n(−t)=0$, $t=1,2,\dots,n−1$, and $H_n(r)=(−1)^dH_n(−n−r)$, $r\ge0$. If you can calculate the answers for some small values of $N,D$ then the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences might have your answers.

Comment: Another paper is MR2023999 (2004k:05009), Beck, Matthias; Cohen, Moshe; Cuomo, Jessica; Gribelyuk, Paul, The number of "magic'' squares, cubes, and hypercubes, Amer. Math. Monthly 110 (2003), no. 8, 707–717. Also, MR2519852 (2010h:52017), De Loera, J. A.; Liu, F.; Yoshida, R., A generating function for all semi-magic squares and the volume of the Birkhoff polytope, J. Algebraic Combin. 30 (2009), no. 1, 113–139.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A122751 and https://oeis.org/A002817 might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have skimmed these papers you mentioned above, later, I find this paper: [The Ehrhart polynomial of the Birkhoﬀ polytope](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dennis/Papers/birkhoff.pdf),  it told me how to get <img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=H_n(t)" style="border:none;">, it's really useful, in the same website, Ehrhart polynomials for n =1, ..., 9  are given [click this link](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dennis/Birkhoff/polynomials.html), that's amazing. Now what i need to do is to read this paper carefully so that I can understand how it comes.

Comment: By the way, could you tell me how to input the math formula with Markdown, like H_n(r) in Latex.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: When you have worked your way through those papers, please come back and write up an answer to summarize what you found.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I write a program to work out how many semi magic squares are there, but there are some problems, could you see my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585776/how-many-semi-magic-squares-are-there).

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, coding is not something I know a whole lot about.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I post a summary of comments, since nobody wrote an answer.</sup>

---

#### Gerry Myerson:

This isn't so easy. There are research papers on the number of such matrices. For the given parameters, might be simplest just to bung it on a computer and count the matrices. This looks useful: [Counting semi-magic squares](http://drvinceknight.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/counting-semi-magic-squares-using.html) from drvinceknight.blogspot.com. I did find a couple of other papers that should help:

> MR0332532 (48 #10859), Ehrhart, Eugène, Sur les carrés magiques, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B 277 (1973), A651–A654. Author's summary: "Le nombre de carrés magiques de côté $c$ et de somme $n$ est un polynôme en $n$ de degré $(c−1)^2$.
>
> MR0317970 (47 #6519), Stanley, Richard P, Linear homogeneous Diophantine equations and magic labelings of graphs, Duke Math. J. 40 (1973), 607–632.

The Stanley paper says, Let $H_n(r)$ denote the number of squares of side $n$, with nonnegative integral entries in each of the $n^2$ cells into which the square can be divided, such that every line-sum in the direction of an edge is $r$. The reviewer noted that $H_n(r)$ is a polynomial in $r$ of degree $d=(n-1)^2$ with rational coefficients, satisfying the relations $H_n(−t)=0$, $t=1,2,\dots,n−1$, and $H_n(r)=(−1)^dH_n(−n−r)$, $r\ge0$. If you can calculate the answers for some small values of $N,D$ then the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences might have your answers.

Two more papers:

> MR2023999 (2004k:05009), Beck, Matthias; Cohen, Moshe; Cuomo, Jessica; Gribelyuk, Paul, The number of "magic'' squares, cubes, and hypercubes, Amer. Math. Monthly 110 (2003), no. 8, 707–717.
>
> MR2519852 (2010h:52017), De Loera, J. A.; Liu, F.; Yoshida, R., A generating function for all semi-magic squares and the volume of the Birkhoff polytope, J. Algebraic Combin. 30 (2009), no. 1, 113–139.

OEIS sequences [oeis.org/A122751](https://oeis.org/A122751) and [oeis.org/A002817](https://oeis.org/A002817) might be helpful.

---

#### user2468587:

I found this paper: [The Ehrhart polynomial of the Birkhoﬀ polytope](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dennis/Papers/birkhoff.pdf),  it told me how to get $H_n(t)$, it's really useful. In the same website, Ehrhart polynomials for $n =1, \dots , 9$   are given, that's amazing.