# How many ways are there to put $mn$ balls of $n$ different colors in $n$ different boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a generalization of exercise number $60$ in Chapter $2$ of Hugh Gordon's *Discrete Probability*.

> We have $m$ balls of each of $n$ different colors. We also have $n$ boxes, each of a different shape. In how many ways can the balls be distributed among the boxes so that each box contains $m$ balls?

The way I read this, there are a total of $mn$ balls. If we order the boxes (which we can without changing the results because they're different shapes) then we can find the number of possibilities for the first $m$ balls (i.e. the first box). Since we could have any color of ball in any amount in the first box, we can use [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to find the number of possibilities. We imagine the color possibilities as the spaces between "bars," so we have $n-1$ bars, and the (uncolored) balls as "stars," so we have $m$ stars. This gives the number of possibilities for just the first box as $$\binom{m+n-1}{n-1}$$

However, the number for the second box varies greatly depending on which configuration the first box is in, so I don't think this method will continue to work. There has to be a better, elegant way to crack this one.

Comment: here is an approach to the problem with $3$ colors http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031257/arrangements-of-3n-balls/1031501#1031501

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is not so easy.  Let us rephrase the question.  You have $n$ boxes, numbered from $1$ to $n$, and you have $n$ colors, also numbered from $1$ to $n$ (say).  Say you have an $n\times n$ square matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is the number of balls of color $i$ contained in the box $j$.  The question then becomes:

> How many $n\times n$ integer matrices with non-negative entries are there such that the sum of the numbers in each row and in each column is $m$?

This was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852966/how-many-nonnegative-integer-matrices-of-size-n-have-all-row-and-column-sums-e).  The answer given there points to several research papers; one of them, [The Ehrhart polynomial of the Birkhoff polytope](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202267v2) by Matthias Beck and Dennis Pixton, says in its introduction that the number we are looking for (called $H_n(m)$ therein) is a polynomial in $m$ of degree $(n-1)^2$, and provides a (computationally heavy) way to compute it.  The results for $n\leq 9$ can be found on [Dennis Pixton's webpage](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dennis/Birkhoff/polynomials.html).

Comment: This problem, with $n=3$, was an exercise in an undergraduate probability book - perhaps the $n=3$ case is much easier? The Ehrhart polynomial for $n=3$ still looks nontrivial, though.

Comment: For $n=3$, the polynomial can also be written as $3\binom{t+3}{4} + \binom{t+2}{2}$. I assume this can be more easily obtained by elementary methods.